# Install Windows 8.1 to 20 laptops using MDT 2013, never done it before

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, installation, images, deployment

I just got the unfortunate job of pushing updating 20 laptops with new images. They are all identical ACER V models that require an identical Windows 8.1 image with a bunch of software. Instead of spending two days doing it one by one I was hoping to use MDT 2013 but when I try to add an OS in the Deployment Workbench it says the install.wim is not there.

I downloaded a WIndows 8.1 image from Microsoft and it comes with an install.esd and I have no idea where or how to get and install.wim. This has turned into the worlds most frustrating day so far.

If you have a suggestion on how to do it not using MDT I would love to hear it as well.

Thank you!

Comment: They gave this type of project to someone who has never done it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if the Windows 8.1 Media is downloaded from either the VLSC or MSDN, the media is presented in .iso format.  The Install.wim file can be located on the original Windows 8.1 Media within the sources folder.  It is named Install.wim.

While this can be used with an unattend.xml (created via the Windows System Image Manager) file to perform an unattended installation, I recommend that you create a new reference image, containing all permanent components that are not subject to change such as Windows Updates and required .NET Frameworks.

The recommended approach would be to create a Build and Capture Task Sequence from within MDT to create your reference image as it will make periodic updates etc. simpler, plus having updates within the reference image itself will prove for a faster overall build.

There is a TechNet article on how to create a reference image below.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn744290.aspx